# Nuxtjs toastr and datatable plugins not working from adminLTE - 3 template

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables, nuxt.js

I have a fresh installed nuxtJs project. I integrated adminLTE in to it via `npm`. I didnt install any UI framework since adminLTE uses bootstrap4 and jquery. But when I use the adminLTE plugins, some doesnt work and some wont show like the toastr and the datatables. I dont have any jquery in my `package.json`. Can someone tell me what did I do wrong? Thanks.

my nuxt config

```
 head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      //All adminLTE css from node_modules/admin-lte/

      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/dist/css/adminlte.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700' }
    ],
    script: [
      //All adminLTE js
      { src: '/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/moment/moment.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/dist/js/adminlte.js', body: true },
      //AdminLte toastr and datatable here
      { src: '/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js', body: true },
      { src: '/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js', body: true }
    ],
```

My component

```
//using toastr
import Vue from 'vue'
import toastr from 'admin-lte/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js'
Vue.use(toastr)
window.toastr = require('toastr')

methods:{
   addDoctor(){
            console.log('hello doc')
            firebase.database().ref('doctors').push({
                name: this.name,
                address: this.address
            }).then((res)=>{
                $('#exampleModal').modal('hide')
                toastr.success('Added!')
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
}
```

The table class

```
 <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
```

The toastr doesnt have an error but when I search in the network->js. I found `toastr.min.js` but the status code is `304`. Also, I got an error in console regarding the data table. Here is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (doctors.vue?78e7:120)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)

and

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:5
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:5
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:5
```

What did I do wrong? Can someone help me about this? thanks

EDIT: Partial fix for toastr. The css was not imported

```
{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css', body: true },
```

thats why the toastr does not show. Toastr issue solved now. Only the data table problem is left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to manually add the jquery and the data table styles to use the datatable class and functions.

in script array

```
  { src: '/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js', body: true },
  { src: '/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js', body: true },
  { src: '/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js', body: true },
```

and in css

```
{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css'}
```